# what is the query to display below output in oracle.

Tags: oracle

[image]

select * from 
(select year,sum(sales) from yqs group by year);

Comment: i tried this one but did not work.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: please add table definition and content in textual form its not recommended to use screenshots of codes in the questions.

Answer (score 4):

```
select
  year,
  quarter,
  sales,
  sum(sales) over (partition by year) as op
from
  yqs
order by
  year,
  quarter;
```

[Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174)